# SQL Putting parts of column name(s) into another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have Result Set that gets populated in a stored procedure and can have dynamic column names.

ex.

```
create table #ResultSet_fields
(
    claimId int,
    adjustmentVersion int,
    ServiceDateFrom date,
    ServiceDateTo date,
    ProcedureCode varchar(10),
    PlaceOfService varchar(3),
    ChangedField varchar(max)
)
```

At runtime the `#ResultSet` can have columns added which end in suffix `_chg`, for example `ProcedureCode_chg` and `PlaceOfService_chg`.

I need to populate `ChangedField` in the result set as `ProcedureCode|PlaceOfService` depending on if the columns `ProcedureCode_chg` and `PlaceOfService_chg` exist and if they're populated with data.

I won't be able to reference the columns directly because I won't know what they are until runtime.

Can someone steer me in the right direction to do this?

Comment: You may need Dynamic SQL for this, a more fleshed out example including sample data and expected results would be useful.

Comment: If you are already struggling to implement this approach, now would be a good time to revisit the decisions that led you to this implementation. Generally speaking, a table should be considered as strongly-typed - it has a fixed and consistent structure. Not only will you struggle to implement this, you will likely struggle to make use of this resultset. Dynamic sql can be used for this - but that requires advanced tsql knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used dynamic approach to prepare the update statement. then you will not hve a problem with the column name. I added ProcedureCode_chg  to check the result. You can make this statement as an alter table statement just after your create
statement.

```
create table #ResultSet_fields(
 claimId int,
 adjustmentVersion int,
 ServiceDateFrom date,
 ServiceDateTo date,
 ProcedureCode varchar(10),
 PlaceOfService varchar(3),
 ChangedField varchar(max),
 test VARCHAR(MAX),
 ProcedureCode_chg varchar(max),
 PlaceOfService_chg varchar(max), --additional columns 
 test_chg varchar(max) -- Additional columns
 )
--test with the below insert
 insert into #ResultSet_fields values (1,1,'2021-08-01','2021-08-01','100', 'A', 'ss', 'test', null,'jj',null)

  IF EXISTS (  SELECT 1  FROM tempDb.sys.columns WHERE [object_ID] = 
      OBJECT_ID('tempDb..#ResultSet_fields')
        AND [name] LIKE '%__chg' )

BEGIN

    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @count_ int   

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id, name  
        INTO #Temp_suffixedColumns
        FROM tempDb.sys.columns WHERE [object_ID] = OBJECT_ID('tempDb..#ResultSet_fields')
        AND [name] LIKE '%__chg'

        DECLARE @count_SuffixedColumns  INT , @counter INT =1 
        SELECT @count_SuffixedColumns = COUNT(1) FROM #Temp_suffixedColumns
 
        WHILE (@counter <= @count_SuffixedColumns)
            BEGIN
 
                SELECT @ColumnName = [name]  
                FROM tempDb.sys.columns 
                WHERE [object_ID] = OBJECT_ID('tempDb..#ResultSet_fields')
                        AND [name] IN ( SELECT  SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX('_chg',name, 0) ) 
                                        FROM #Temp_suffixedColumns 
                                        WHERE   [name]    LIKE '%__chg' AND id = @counter)
    
     
                 SET @SQL =   'Update #ResultSet_fields SET ChangedField =  '''+  @ColumnName +''' 
                    FROM #ResultSet_fields where (' +@ColumnName+'_chg is not null or ' +@ColumnName+'_chg <> '''')'
    
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL 
                SET @counter = @counter +1

                --SELECT @SQL

            END   
    
END

  --to check the update is correct
   SELECT * FROM #ResultSet_fields
   DROP TABLE #ResultSet_fields 
   DROP TABLE #Temp_suffixedColumns
```

Comment: @H22 let me know if this helps or need changes. Happy to help :)

Comment: I appreciate the help but I don't think I explained my problem well enough. The issue with @ColumnName is that there can be multiple columns in the results set with the '_chg' suffix and I need to update them all. It may be back to the drawing board for this problem. Thanks again!

Comment: @H22 that means ChangedField   can be updated from ProcedureCode or PlaceOfService as of the exitance of corresponding _chg sufixed column? Let me change the answer and add.

Comment: Test case 1: ProcedureCode_chg then  set ChangedField  = ProcedureCode    
Test case 2 : PlaceOfService_chg then  set ChangedField  = PlaceOfService
Test Case 3:  PlaceOfService_chg  and   ProcedureCode_chg  then   ChangedField   = isnull (ProcedureCode   , PlaceOfService) 
and this is a dynamic pocess as you cannot gurantee how many columns can be added in run time with sufix _chg . Am I clear with your requirement ? @H22

Comment: That is right except test case 1 would be ChangedField = 'ProcedureCode', Case 2: ChangedField = 'PlaceOfService',Case 3: ChangedField = 'ProcedureCode | PlaceOfService'.

Comment: And yes it will be dynamic and will not know how many columns at run time with the '_chg' suffix.

Comment: Will try to acheive this. but this is little complex

Comment: @H22 Added the answer again, i tested using three _chg columns and it works fine, Let me know if this helps or need more alterations.  Thanks

Comment: This is almost exactly it, though I need the literal string 'ProcedureCode' or literal 'ProcedureCode | PlaceOfService' to go into ChangedField, not the data itself. Also is there a way to only grab the columns if they are populated with data instead of just grabbing it if it exists? I appreciate all the help. I am really learning a lot of advanced tsql because of this.

Comment: coalesce  function in SQL does this. so you need to worry. It updates based on the availability of the values in the column

Comment: I think now your answer is all good. Let me know. This is tested for test cases and let me know if you have any concerns @H22

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. The only thing I had to tweak was adding additional quotation marks around column name where the update says: Set ChangedField = . Can you fix that in the answer so I can accept it. Thanks again, you're an amazing help and SQL programmer.

Comment: sure ill fix it and give you, can you add me what you need there here? And y you need an additional quotation ? if you add additional quotation it will do some changes in the dynamic code, is it '[' , ']' or ' '   ?

Comment: SET ChangedField =  ''' +  @ColumnName + '''

Comment: Done, I will add a second way as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the columns already exists and also chekc if theay are not null#

> ```
> create table #ResultSet_fields(
>  claimId int,
>  adjustmentVersion int,
>  ServiceDateFrom date,
>  ServiceDateTo date,
>  ProcedureCode varchar(10),
>  PlaceOfService varchar(3),
>  ChangedField varchar(max)
>  )
> ```

> ```
> IF COL_LENGTH('#ResultSet_fields', 'ProcedureCode_chg') IS NOT NULL ANd COL_LENGTH('#ResultSet_fields', 'ProcedureCode_chg') IS NOT NULL
> BEGIN
>     UPDATE #ResultSet_fields SET ChangedField = ProcedureCode + PlaceOfService;
> END
> GO
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b827317b872ddc8217376840cd3f917)*

Comment: Thanks but I won't know the column names until runtime. It could be any columnname in the resultset + '_chg'

Comment: that makes no difference, wxtwnd the example to all clumns, and when you want the chanfield to conatain all simple  use a varuqable that gets all comölumn names or content and add to that variable and only at the end you update the column, but that ios outside iof the scope of the question, besides there are **audit** solutions for that kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

Check system tables in tempdb for if column names like "%_Chn" exist at runtime and if so you should be able to continue processing for the column(s) that exist with change suffix and then do more logic on evaluating what exists in those columns.. trick will be that is you need to dynamically build/execute sql statements you could do that within calling program language or if want to do that right on DBMS you might be able to build sqlstring dynamically then execute that string (you'd need to create set variables and string together sqlstatement based on what is in tempdb columns name returned by below...

```
create table #ResultSet_fields
(
 PlaceOfService varchar(3),
 PlaceOfService_Chg varchar(3),
 ColumnX varchar(3),
 ColumnX_Chg varchar(3),
 ColumnY varchar(3)
)
 
select 
name as ChangeField,
substring(name,1,charindex('_Chg',name)-1) as SisterField
from tempdb.sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#ResultSet_fields')
and name like '%_Chg'
```